# Specification By Example: how to manage low level details

Tags: bdd, acceptance-testing, specifications

I  need advice of an expert in BDD/ATTD/Specification by example. 
(Sorry for a long essay,  I didn't know how to express the problem in a fewer words)

**Problem description**

We've been working on a medium-size project for about 1 year.
The team's using a flow-based process driven by acceptance tests (written in a form of detailed test cases).

And now, as the requirements evolve we started having problems with maintainability of those tests.

1. They are (very) hard to read an definitely don't serve as a product
   specification
2. Slight change in requirements results in many days
   refactoring as the tests are too coupled with implementation details

**How we see it solved**

To solve the problem we're going to convert our tests into executable specifications. 
All the books/articles I've read (e.g. Specification by example by Gojko Adzic) recommend that we don't overload specs with low levels details which tell rather ***how*** a product should be implemented instead of ***what*** a product should do to meet the business expectation.

That seems to be reasonable as the specs would likely be more readable and maintainable and reflect a business goal and not a software design when not  overspecified.
However, these low level details cannot be just thrown away - though they are not explicitly asked by the business user, they are still anticipated. For instance if a user presses 'Process button' it had better be disabled and 'Cancel button' enabled until the processing is complete. Details like this seem to be unnecessary in the spec but are required for an app to be accepted by the customer.

We use (A)TDD on every level and are used to writing code only to make a test pass. Now instead of detailed tests we'll have more abstract executable specs and simply do not understand where to put those low level details.

**Question**

So, could someone suggest a good practice of managing low level requirements that can't go to the specification?

Answer (score 2):

I think that describing step as `When user presses 'Process button'` is definitely tell us **how** system should be implemented, instead of describing **what** product should do for business. What do we know from this step? Only that we have button (not link, not some other control) somewhere on the UI, which has text `Process` on it. Nothing about business. And even worse - it's very brittle. If you change button's text to `Start` this step will be invalid. Same if you change control type.

Clicking on buttons is not business goal. So, how to describe business goal? I think `When user starts processing bills` is good definition of step. If you change UI, this behavior will stay same. It's not brittle any more. Only implementation of step will change.

Comment: Thanks, but your post rather repeats what I've said - an overspecified spec is not a good idea - but does not answer my question. Such a requirement still needs checking (because it's rather a common sense expected from a good app). If it is not in spec, then probably it would be tested manually during test execution phase (and then will become a part of manual regression suite) - which is not what we want either. Should we keep a separate specification with UI  interaction and mock-ups? Should we check such things on unit test level or test automation layer behind the executable specs?

Comment: @olldman actually I pointed that UI-related details should go to implementation of step (e.g. if you use Speclfow details will go to steps definition file). When domain expert will look through scenarios it will see domain he is expert of `When user starts processing bills` instead of UI domain staff. I recommend you to read this nice Dan North article on topic http://dannorth.net/2011/01/31/whose-domain-is-it-anyway/

Comment: I think I start seeing your point. The thing I still a bit concerned is that a spec is not only for a domain expert but for a person who will be implementing the feature. In your project, would you leave these details up to developers to take care of? Shouldn't it be specified elsewhere?

Comment: @olldman I think developers are technical enough to read the definition of step :) So, when you have step `When user starts processing bills`, you go to step definition and start designing your application. You don't have button `Process` until you meet this business scenario. Thus you start with code, which presses non-existing button on some form/page, which you have designed in `Given` step. After you defined what is `done` means for this business requirement, developers start to implement steps. They will have details, which should be implemented (in steps definitions).